# How to insert one row at a time in SQL using cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

Hi i am using the below PLSQL script to insert rows in new table new_table.

```
set serveroutput on SIZE 1000000;
DECLARE
CURSOR get_record IS
SELECT * from cycle_table ;
BEGIN
FOR rec IN get_record
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Inserting Record into new_table..');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('insert into new_table
                  select cycle_code,cycle_instance,cycle_start_date,cycle_end_date
                  from cycle_table');
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Now the table cycle_table consist only 4 rows. The loop runs only four times beacuse its printing 'Inserting Record into new_table..' 4 times only.

But when i see the new_table it consist 16 rows. Which means everytime the loop iterates it insert all the 4 rows and thus total 16 rows.

What i want is that it insert single row at a time.
So that i can perform other actions on that row also. Like if the row already exist, insert in some other table or anything.

Please suggest what can I do here? I am using SQL developer on oracle 10g

Thanks in advance

Comment: The INSERT you execute does exactly that: it inserts all rows from the other table. Don't use SQL literals but create the insert based on the row the cursor points to.

Comment: Its a RBAR scenario. You can do the insert using set based approach instead of using cursor.

Comment: @SelvaTS I have to use cursor only. There are other operation that need to be done. And that can be done with cursor only.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hi, can u help me with that. How can i create insert that only insert the row the cursor points to. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple:

```
set serveroutput on SIZE 1000000;
DECLARE
BEGIN
    FOR rec in (select * from cycle_table)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Inserting Record into new_table..');
    insert into new_table (cycle_code, 
                           cycle_instance, 
                           cycle_start_date, 
                           cycle_end_date)
                   values (rec.cycle_code, 
                           rec.cycle_instance, 
                           rec.cycle_start_date, 
                           rec.cycle_end_date);

    END LOOP;


    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I would discourage this approach, though, as you could run into a performance issue if there is a large number of records. You have only four, so it's fine.

The reason I'm against this is that there is context switching involved between Oracle's PL/SQL engine and SQL engine. I'd suggest you do an `insert into .... select...` or use a `forall` instead, as these are the least resource-consuming approaches.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But yes there will be huge records in the table. This is only for the testing purpose i have stored only 4 rows in the table. Can u plz tel me the other way   "insert into .... select... or use a forall "

Comment: You have already used it in the PL/SQL block in your question. Just get rid of the `execute immediate`, the cursor and the loop, simply keep the `insert into` query and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way is to eliminate all of the looping, and allow the SQL to handle everything. Here is my suggestion:

```
BEGIN

   -- Handle matches first, because after you handle non-matches, everything matches
   INSERT INTO match_table (cycle_code, cycle_instance, cycle_start_date
                          , cycle_end_date)
      SELECT cycle_table.cycle_code, cycle_table.cycle_instance, cycle_table.cycle_start_date
           , cycle_table.cycle_end_date
        FROM cycle_table INNER JOIN new_table ON (new_table.cycle_code = cycle_table.cycle_code);

   -- Single insert to insert all non matching records
   INSERT INTO new_table (cycle_code, cycle_instance, cycle_start_date
                        , cycle_end_date)
      SELECT cycle_code, cycle_instance, cycle_start_date
           , cycle_end_date
        FROM cycle_table
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT NULL
                   FROM new_table
                  WHERE new_table.cycle_code = cycle_table.cycle_code);

   COMMIT;
END;
```